# Creating django users using two different ways

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

I tried creating `User`s (`django.contrib.auth.models.User`) in django via two different ways:

1. Using `User.objects.create(username="<username_here>", password="<password_here>", email="<email_here>)` -> When I use this, loggin users in and all the other benefits the come with `auth.models.User` are not received, for example, I cannot use `authenticate` on users created this way.
2. Using `User.objects.create_user("<username>", "<email>", "<password>")`. Doing things this way has no problems and you can use all the free stuff that comes with django's `auth` app.

My question is, why is this the case?

Comment: In the first case, you need to use `set_password` function after creating.

Comment: @sneawo A more elaborate answer would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `create_user` method, you'll find that for password it uses `set_password` method.

```
def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
    """
    now = timezone.now()
    if not username:
        raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
    email = UserManager.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(username=username, email=email,
                      is_staff=False, is_active=True, is_superuser=False,
                      last_login=now, date_joined=now)

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

Answer (score 0):

Django's passwords are not stored as simple text, that is, the password *per se*. It's actually a hash string that Django uses to validate a given password ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.password)).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the `create_user` function is a helper function that takes the value you put for password and runs it through [Django's password hasher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password) that takes an "in the clear password" like "i like cats" and makes it safer for storage as "0mvu3kmiXHh$qhVGuNyO9cvV5spWeFrt9/ZhIR81GcvAGVKMgILwpkU=". So when you use the `create` instead of `create_user` you just passed an "in the clear" password as the password, which will not work since when the user types in "i like cats" it will be hash and compared, which will fail since you set their password directly instead of using Django's hasher.